# Using variable names and emails in .net mail FROM section

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am creating a form which is going to be used to voice support for a local initiative. The form needs to have the option to show the display name, as well email that the user enters - as opposed to them all coming from the form domain such as advocates@mysite.com.  So in my for I have two fields for this purpose, the txtNameFrom and the txtEmailFrom.  I am using them as so:

```
//mail.From = new MailAddress("advocates@mysite.com", "mysite advocates");
mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmailFrom.ToString(), txtNameFrom.ToString());
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("adv1@mysite.com"));
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("adv2@mysite.com"));
mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
```

So the line I have commented out works perfectly, however once I throw variables in there I receive the following error:

```
[FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.]
```

So I am assuming the ToString() must be incorrect, but not sure which else to try - if this is even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: _"but not sure which else to try"_ - you have an exception, debug it. Put a breakpoint on the line throwing the error and inspect `txtEmailFrom.ToString()`. It will display something like `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, so apparently `ToString()` isn't what you want, as that isn't a valid email address. Refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) of the class and realize you need the `Text` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
txtEmailFrom.ToString()
```

To

```
txtEmailFrom.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.ToString()` is indeed incorrect.  Assuming that `txtEmailFrom` is a `TextBox` then calling `.ToString()` on it will return something like:

```
"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"
```

Or whatever the fully-qualified name for that type is.  What you're looking for is the `.Text` property on that object:

```
txtEmailFrom.Text
```

Resulting in:

```
mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmailFrom.Text, txtNameFrom.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `Text` value of the textbox, you're calling `ToString` on the object directly which is printing out `System.Web.TextBox` or something similar. Use the `Text` property:

```
mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmailFrom.Text, txtNameFrom.Text)
```